# why is the node list not showing in my console

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

so im just starting to learn java script. my problem is that my console is not showing the node list

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>rock paper scissors</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button class="playerHand">
        <img src="https://cdn.picpng.com/rock/rock-boulder-stone-nature-73801.png" alt="img">
    </button>

    <button class="playerHand">
        <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/cthoman/cthoman1506/cthoman150600151/41655963-a-cartoon-piece-of-paper-happy-and-smiling-.jpg" alt="img">
    </button>

    <button class="playerHand">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/88/3c/90/883c9023342352e3b62f11b0858e545b.jpg" alt="img">
    </button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
console.log('hello word');

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playerHand");

console.log(buttons);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVuRk.png)

the length should be 3 not 0

i tried using an online code editor and it worked but i dont want to use an online editor

Comment: i tried that it didnt work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are loading the file that time dom is still being ready. that's why its not coming up, try this.  just to test this, you can add one more button to see what is the difference in logging before dom is ready. or you write script loading at the end of the body.

Javascript code:

```
console.log('hello word');

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playerHand");
console.log(buttons)

function readDocument() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".playerHand");
    console.log(buttons)
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>rock paper scissors</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button class="playerHand">
        <img src="https://cdn.picpng.com/rock/rock-boulder-stone-nature-73801.png" alt="img">
    </button>

    <button class="playerHand">
        <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/cthoman/cthoman1506/cthoman150600151/41655963-a-cartoon-piece-of-paper-happy-and-smiling-.jpg" alt="img">
    </button>

    <button class="playerHand">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/88/3c/90/883c9023342352e3b62f11b0858e545b.jpg" alt="img">
    </button>
    
    <button onclick="readDocument()">Load Nodelist</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill his requirements. It needs to be both a button and have the class `playerHand`.

Comment: yes it worked thank you weirdly my original code only worked on an online code editore anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because only classes use `.` in querySelector. Element names don't use anything. Here's a solution (only 2 lines!):

```js
var selected = document.querySelectorAll('button.playerHand');
console.log(selected)
```

```html
<button class="playerHand">
  <img src="https://cdn.picpng.com/rock/rock-boulder-stone-nature-73801.png" alt="img">
</button>

<button class="playerHand">
  <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/cthoman/cthoman1506/cthoman150600151/41655963-a-cartoon-piece-of-paper-happy-and-smiling-.jpg" alt="img">
</button>

<button class="playerHand">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/88/3c/90/883c9023342352e3b62f11b0858e545b.jpg" alt="img">
</button>
```

Also, remember to execute the JavaScript after the page is ready, or you might have some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and I solved by adding the attribute `defer` on the script tag. I always add that, but for that time I forgot and spent more than an hour trying a lot of JS stuffs and was just a simple html thing, LOL...

```html
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
```

If you don't know what `defer` does, just take a look at [this quick tutorial by Web Dev Simplified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMuFBYw91UQ&pp=ugMICgJwdBABGAE%3D)